# How to enable font ligatures in Android Studio 2.0?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I've been trying to use [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) with its awesome programming ligatures in Android Studio 2.0.

Upon looking on FiraCode's [installation guide for IntelliJ IDEs](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Intellij-products-instructions), it said that I should enable a flag in the `idea.properties` file likewise:

```
editor.enable.optional.ligatures=true
```

I've tried to look it up in IntelliJ's guide on how to achieve this. The guide states that I should be able to edit the file in question via the Help menu:

> You can create an empty file idea.properties and open it in the editor by choosing the Help | Edit Custom Properties command on the main menu.

But I just can't find it in my setup. Is this achievable in Android Studio 2.0?

Comment: `idea.properties` can be found under the `android-studio/bin` directory in linux or `Android Studio.app/Contents/bin` on osx.

Answer (score 8):

At the Android Studio menu bar, Go to *Help* > *Edit Custom Properties...*. If you've never created this file before, Android Studio will ask if you want to create it. Click "Yes" and then in the new file, copy and paste the entry

```
editor.enable.optional.ligatures=true
```

and restart the IDE.

The above steps works with IntelliJ IDEA and Pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works, try this:

1. Click the "Save As" button in Font menu for Scheme and save new
   custom scheme. After that, try enabling the font ligatures.
2. Then if in the primary font options you do not have "Fira Code"
   download and install it from https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode
3. Restart android studio

Hope it works, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.<CONFIGURATION_FOLDER>/
Mac: ~/Library/Preferences/<CONFIGURATION_FOLDER>/
Linux: ~/.<CONFIGURATION_FOLDER>/
```

In my particular it's `!/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/`

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html